# How to represent the given quadratic equation into the tensor notation and find the solutions?

Tags: quadratic-forms

I have derived an equation which exists as $$p^2+{2 p \cos\alpha} \, {\chi} +\chi^2=\left( \frac{v^2} r\right)^2$$ which I hope could be transformed analogously into the form of function $F(x,y)=ax^2+2bxy+cy^2$ where, $(x,y)$ implies $(p,\chi)$. But how to represent it into tensor notation and solve for $p$ and $\chi$?

Comment: It’s a really bad idea to use both ‘$a$’ and ‘$\alpha$’ in the same equation. They look too much alike in the standard fonts that are used here.

Comment: Please don't consider about notation, I simply want the solution.

Comment: You’re much more likely to get a response if you *don’t* make your question hard to read.